# 'PresentPaymentSheetParameters' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Parameters are now inherited from initPaymentSheet

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe Payment Gateway into my e-commerce application. I am new to stripe payment gateway, I am facing a depreciation error which is as

> 'parameters' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Params are now inherited from initPaymentSheet so this 'parameters' can be removed.

The current stripe plugin I am using is flutter_stripe: ^3.3.0. Just want to know how to fix this depreciation issue. Attaching the error screenshot also

CODE IS AS :

```
displayPaymentSheet(OrderProvider orderProvider) async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance
          .presentPaymentSheet(
              parameters: PresentPaymentSheetParameters(
        clientSecret: paymentIntentData!['client_secret'],
        confirmPayment: true,
      ))
          .then((newValue) {
        print('payment intent ${paymentIntentData!['id']}');
        print('payment intent ${paymentIntentData!['client_secret']}');
        print('payment intent ${paymentIntentData!['amount']}');
        print('payment intent $paymentIntentData');
        //orderPlaceApi(paymentIntentData!['id'].toString());
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: const Text("Paid successfully")));
        orderProvider.success = true;
        Navigator.pop(context);
        setState(() {
          paymentIntentData = null;
        });
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        print('Exception/DISPLAYPAYMENTSHEET==> $error $stackTrace');
      });
    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      print('Exception/DISPLAYPAYMENTSHEET==> $e');
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                content: Text("Cancelled "),
              ));
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
    }
  }
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `initPaymentSheet`.

```dart
await Stripe.instance
    .initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        paymentIntentClientSecret: "",
      ),
    )
```

Comment: And you can directly access `await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet()`

Comment: await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet() this worked thanks